# How to give a dynamic name for an XML file while creating XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am a new to Programming. I am creating a XML file using windows forms and the name of my XML file is the name field text-box text of windows forms, Its working fine but if the file is already available i want to give new name but i am able to give different name only once. For example if 'dog.xml' is already there then i am able to create dog1.xml file then whenever i am creating any new file the content of the 'dog1.xml' file replaced with new file content but i want to create 'dog11.xml' or 'dog2.xml' file

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    path = rtxtName.Text + ".xml";//name of a xml file is name of WPF 'name' field 
    doc = new XmlDocument(); //Here i am creating the xmldocument object
    doc.CreateTextNode(path);
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))//if there is no file exists then
    {
        CreateNewXMLDoc();
    }
    else
    {
        path = rtxtName.Text + "1.xml"; //If the file is already avaliable          
        CreateNewXMLDoc();
    }
}

public void CreateNewXMLDoc() //This method is for creating my xml file
{
    XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
    XmlComment comment = doc.CreateComment("This is a generated XML file");
    doc.AppendChild(declaration);
    doc.AppendChild(comment);
    doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("root"));
}
```

Comment: Do you really think your problem is related with xml?

Comment: Your code is working fine on how to change name, where is your problem?

Comment: As far as I can tell, he wants it  to be able to save it as something2.xml if something1.xml exists, or something3.xml if the first 2 exist(actually 3, if you include something.xml).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        path = rtxtName.Text;//name of a xml file is name of WPF 'name' field 

        doc = new XmlDocument(); //Here i am creating the xmldocument object

        string tempPath = path;
        int counter = Properties.Settings.Default.Counter;

        while(System.IO.File.Exists(tempPath))
        {
            counter++;
            tempPath = path + counter + ".xml";
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Counter = counter;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        doc.CreateTextNode(path);
        CreateNewXMLDoc();
    }
```

If you would like to be fancy and follow Microsofts standards, then change the path to this
you can build in the  something - Copy.xml then something - Copy (1).xml, etc.

```
tempPath = path + "(" + counter + ")" + ".xml";
```

**EDIT**

Updated to keep the counter when the application restarts

Comment: It is working fine but when i close my application then again counter value becomes zero. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't know you needed to save the counter, although what happens when a previous one is removed?  ie something1.xml doesnt exist anymore, do you want it to continue from the last one (ie something5.xml or try save it as something1.xml again?

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default doesn't contain the definition of 'Counter' should i import some namespace?

Comment: Go to the properties form of your project, and then click on the settings tab.  Then create a counter setting there, of type int.